# Centering text in footer without text-align center

Tags: html, css, alignment

From [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0z9g7jp/), you can see that I have a footer.

I would like to align the content within each column so that the container is centered, but the text still aligned left.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="left">
  <div class="align">
    <h6>Facebook</h6>
    <h6>Twitter</h6>
    <h6>Blog</h6>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="align">
    <h6>Privacy Policy</h6>
    <h6>Terms of Service</h6>
    <h6>Help</h6>
    <h6>Contact Us</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
  width: 50%;
}

.left {
   float: left;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}

.align {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Will the text always be a `h6` element?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: "centered left" make no sense. Perhaps an image of the desired result would be of more use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this

```css
.left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
}
.right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
.hor-center {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <div class="hor-center">
    <h6>Facebook</h6>
    <h6>Reddit</h6>
    <h6>Instagram</h6>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="right">
  <div class="hor-center">
    <h6>Terms</h6>
    <h6>F&amp;Q</h6>
    <h6>Email</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The text is still aligned center, I would like it so the container is centered but the text as it is, centered left.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a width on a block level container and give it `margin: 0 auto;`. You can change the 0, which controls top and bottom margins, but the key is having a definite width with auto left and right margins.

Comment: This is the first thing I tried but didn't show the results I wanted.

Comment: Hi Pav. There's no reason to change a div from `block` (it's initial display setting) to `table`. The effect here is identical.